# Non-viral open-source PDF library

Tags: pdf, open-source, licensing

I'd like to embed a PDF file viewer in a window of my planned-to-be open-source application. I don't want to release my application on GPL though, and most of open-source PDF libraries are on GPL (poppler, ghostscript, muPDF).

Is there a PDF viewer library that would be on a non-viral open-source license?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure what you're doing will require you to adopt the GPL? I suggest you read some of the guides, because many times it's not as strict as people sometimes advocate, especially if you aren't changing (poppler|ghostscript|myPDF|etc) itself.

Comment: @chmullig: for now I'd rather be on the safe side. If I find nothing, then maybe I'll consider using them somehow...

Comment: It's a shame, these are indeed GPL and not LGPL. If they would be LGPL it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a new BSD-licensed contender: [PDFium](https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Raedwald: what would you like to be added to this answer, then, in the context of this specific question? The answer specifies that the mentioned software package is indeed on a free non-viral license.

Answer (score 0):

IANAL.  Blah blah blah.

Using GhostScript by shelling out to a command line will not require you to change your licensing in any way.  Batch files used to call GhostScript aren't automagically GPL'ed.

With GPL, I'd always understood that it boiled down to "Separate process?  Separate license!".

So you just have GS whip up a relatively hi DPI version of the PDF page in question, and let the user pan and zoom around in that.  Because GS IS in a separate process, you could fire off additional page requests in the background so the user won't perceive a delay when paging back and forth.  GS takes a page range as one of its conversion parameters.

What you couldn't do is generate an image of a small part of an individual PDF page at high DPI/zoom.  IIRC, you have to render the whole page.

Comment: Let me note that the question was different. I am not asking for a law advice. I understand there are ways to evade some GPL restrictions, but I am not looking for them right now.

Comment: The problem behind your question is "I need something to render PDFs to pixels so I can show them on screen".  I'm addressing that... but you're correct, I didn't answer your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is open source and free then you should consider the option to host Adobe Reader ActiveX control (which requires to have Adobe Reader to be installed), this behavior would be the same as embedded Adobe Reader in Internet Explorer or Firefox browsers.

Lot of users have Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader installed on their computers already.

Comment: This will work only on Windows... but thanks for idea.